# IPFS add and read file from node

Tags: ipfs

I am currently playing around with IPFS in a docker container. I am able to send HTTP requests to the API using curl. I created a small text file with some text. I would like to add the file with the content to the node and retrieve it afterwards.

So I did:

```
curl -F file=test.txt http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add
```

and received the response

```
{"Name":"QmYregh1mU7otV4s37hXLKnJ2fk2e8yFbJmU9L9cM6yrQM",
 "Hash":"QmYregh1mU7otV4s37hXLKnJ2fk2e8yFbJmU9L9cM6yrQM",
"Size":"16"}
```

Now I would like to read the file with and save it on my local machine. I used

```
 curl http://localhost:5001/api/v0/cat?arg=QmYregh1mU7otV4s37hXLKnJ2fk2e8yFbJmU9L9cM6yrQM
```

to retrieve the file. The response is

```
test.txt
```

My question is now: How do I get the content of the file?

Comment: you should try to cast that to a string, basically `toString()` on the received payload

Comment: Cast? I used the commands in a terminal. How could a cast help here?

Comment: I suggest you try something like postman and see if you can change the preview of the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [cat](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/http/api/#api-v0-cat):

```
curl -X POST "https://ipfs.elastoscarrier.org/api/v0/cat?arg=QmYregh1mU7otV4s37hXLKnJ2fk2e8yFbJmU9L9cM6yrQM"
```

This will return the content of the added file.

Answer (score 0):

To download IPFS objects using the HTTP API you need to use `GET`. As you can read in the [docs](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/http/#api-v0-get).

> **/api/v0/get**
>
> Download IPFS objects.
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - `arg` [string]: The path to the IPFS object(s) to be outputted. Required: **yes**.
> - `output` [string]: The path where the output should be stored. Required: no.
> - `archive` [bool]: Output a TAR archive. Required: no.
> - `compress` [bool]: Compress the output with GZIP compression. Required: no.
> - `compression-level` [int]: The level of compression (1-9). Required: no.

For your example, something like the following should work:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:5001/api/v0/get?arg=QmYregh1mU7otV4s37hXLKnJ2fk2e8yFbJmU9L9cM6yrQM&archive=false" >> myfile
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2048    0  2048    0     0   666k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  666k
$ cat myfile
QmYregh1mU7otV4s37hXLKnJ2fk2e8yFbJmU9L9cM6yrQM0000644000000000000000000000001013567560642017027 0ustar0000000000000000test.txt
```

The content (`test.txt`) is shown at the end of the line. As you can see, I've used only one argument (`archive=false`) and doesn't work because I'm still getting a `tar` file. Please read about that [here](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/download-more-bytes-when-using-curl-command/562).

For your interest, it's possible to download objects using [CLI commands](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/cli/#ipfs-get):

```
get <ref>     Download IPFS objects
```

Example:

```
$ ipfs get QmYregh1mU7otV4s37hXLKnJ2fk2e8yFbJmU9L9cM6yrQM
Saving file(s) to QmYregh1mU7otV4s37hXLKnJ2fk2e8yFbJmU9L9cM6yrQM
 8 B / 8 B [========================================================================================================================================================] 100.00% 0s
$ cat QmYregh1mU7otV4s37hXLKnJ2fk2e8yFbJmU9L9cM6yrQM 
test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found the answer by looking at **curl**'s manual. The issue has nothing to do with the IPFS API, it's the format of your curl command that is causing the problem.
instead of `curl -F file=test.txt http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add`, the correct command is `curl -F file=@test.txt http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add` with the added `@` before the filepath.
Then to get a good output when you read the file, use **api/v0/cat** instead of **api/v0/get**.